# Seaborn Heatmap: underline text in a cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, underline

I am making some data analysis in Python, and I am using Seaborn for visualization.
Seaborn works very nice for creating heatmaps.

I am trying to underline the maximum values for each column in my heatmap.

I was able to correctly highlight the text in the maximum cells by making them *italic* and **bold**. Still, I found no way to underline it.

This is an example of my code:

```py
data_matrix = < extract my data and put them into a matrix >
max_in_each_column = np.max(data_matrix, axis=0)

sns.heatmap(data_matrix,
            mask=data_matrix == max_in_each_column,
            linewidth=0.5,
            annot=True,
            xticklabels=my_x_tick_labels,
            yticklabels=my_y_tick_labels,
            cmap="coolwarm_r")

sns.heatmap(data_matrix,
            mask=data_matrix != max_in_each_column,
            annot_kws={"style": "italic", "weight": "bold"},
            linewidth=0.5,
            annot=True,
            xticklabels=my_x_tick_labels,
            yticklabels=my_y_tick_labels,
            cbar=False,
            cmap="coolwarm_r")
```

This is my current result:
[image: My current heatmap, with maximum values for each column *italic* and **bold**]

Of course I have tried using argument`annot_kws={"style": "underlined"}`, but apparently in Seaborn the "style" key only supports values "normal", "italic" or "oblique".

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You can use `text` option from matplotlib to put annotations and turn the annotations off during seaborn plotting. You should provide a working example for more help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can workaround your problem using tex commands within your texts. The basic idea is that you use the `annot` key of `seaborn.heatmap` to assign an array of strings as text labels. These contain your data values + some tex prefixes/suffixes to allow tex making them bold/emphasized (italic)/underlined or whatsoever.

An example (with random numbers):

```
# random data
data_matrix = np.round(np.random.rand(10, 10), decimals=2)
max_in_each_column = np.max(data_matrix, axis=0)

# Activating tex in all labels globally
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
# Adjust font specs as desired (here: closest similarity to seaborn standard)
plt.rc('font', **{'size': 14.0})
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{lmodern}')

# remains unchanged
sns.heatmap(data_matrix,
            mask=data_matrix == max_in_each_column,
            linewidth=0.5,
            annot=True,
            cmap="coolwarm_r")

# changes here
sns.heatmap(data_matrix,
            mask=data_matrix != max_in_each_column,
            linewidth=0.5,
            # Use annot key with np.array as value containing strings of data + latex 
            # prefixes/suffices making the bold/italic/underline formatting
            annot=np.array([r'\textbf{\emph{\underline{' + str(data) + '}}}'
                            for data in data_matrix.ravel()]).reshape(
                np.shape(data_matrix)),
            # fmt key must be empty, formatting error otherwise
            fmt='',
            cbar=False,
            cmap="coolwarm_r")

plt.show()
```

Further explanation the annotation array:

```
# For all matrix_elements in your 2D data array (2D requires the .ravel() and .reshape() 
# stuff at the end) construct in sum a 2D data array consisting of strings 
# \textbf{\emph{\underline{<matrix_element>}}}. Each string will be represented by tex as 
# a bold, italic and underlined representation of the matrix_element
np.array([r'\textbf{\emph{\underline{' + str(data) + '}}}'
                        for data in data_matrix.ravel()]).reshape(np.shape(data_matrix))
```

The resulting plot is basically what you wanted:

[image]